# Remove unicode char in a POST body

Tags: json, django, unicode, django-rest-framework

Using Django Rest Framework, a JSON containing the unicode char \x0b makes a 400 bad request error.

I'm trying to change my request data to remove this unicode char:

```
 def initialize_request(self, request, *args, **kwargs):    
         data = request.body
         new_data = data.decode('utf-8')
         new_data = new_data.replace('\x0b', '')
         request.body = new_data.encode('utf-8')

         r = super(ScanListCreateAPIView, self).initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)

         return r
```

but this returns a "can't set attribute" error.

Is there a way to alter the 'body' attribute? Or to clone the old request to a new request?

Comment: That is not a solution, you have to figure out why it throw 400 bad request error. do you have a back-trace for that error?

Comment: Could you post your entire view class? Are you sure the `400` status is not generated by your `serializer_class`?

Comment: I have ""detail": "JSON parse error - Invalid control character at: line 1 column 873 (char 872)", char 872" / and char 872 is "\xc2"

Comment: @RenanIvo serializer class is not called

Comment: Note that \x0b cannot appear literally in a JSON file, control characters must be escaped (as `\u000b` in this case).